# How to convert array into JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

I have an array like this (which is similar to a JSON array) of length n:

```
const mainData = [
  {
    phrase: "Phrase 1",
    categorynumber: 1,
    optionnumber: 1,
  },
  {
    phrase: "Phrase 2",
    categorynumber: 1,
    optionnumber: 2,
  },
  {
    phrase: "Phrase 3",
    categorynumber: 2,
    optionnumber: 1,
  },
  {
    phrase: "Phrase 4",
    categorynumber: 3,
    optionnumber: 1,
  },
  {
    phrase: "Phrase 5",
    categorynumber: 3,
    optionnumber: 1,
  },
  {
    phrase: "Phrase 6",
    categorynumber: 3,
    optionnumber: 2,
  },
];
```

I would like to convert it into a nested Object like so:

```
jsObject = {
  1: {
    1: ["Phrase 1"],
    2: ["Phrase 2"],
  },
  2: {
    1: ["Phrase 3"],
  },
  3: {
    1: ["Phrase 4", "Phrase 5"],
    2: ["Phrase 6"],
  },
};
```

Essentially, the object is categorised according to the `categorynumber` and then `optionnumber`. (Please keep the format of "Phrase 4" and "Phrase 5" in view.)

Comment: Looks like an iteration and two-step object creation/mapping--what specific issue are you having with your code? I don't see it posted here.

Comment: array reduce....

Comment: I am looking for ways on how to approach this. I have not written any specific code yet.

Comment: SO expects a minimum amount of effort from users asking questions to write some code first. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the dataset by accessing the `categorynumber` as the main key, and the  `optionnumber` as the subkey. You can apply new options to the existing category by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) the new option and wrapping it within an array.

If you are appending additional phrases, you will need to also grab the existing array and spread the new value.

```js
const mainData = [
  { phrase: "Phrase 1", categorynumber: 1, optionnumber: 1, },
  { phrase: "Phrase 2", categorynumber: 1, optionnumber: 2, },
  { phrase: "Phrase 3", categorynumber: 2, optionnumber: 1, },
  { phrase: "Phrase 4", categorynumber: 3, optionnumber: 1, },
  { phrase: "Phrase 5", categorynumber: 3, optionnumber: 1, },
  { phrase: "Phrase 6", categorynumber: 3, optionnumber: 2, },
];

const jsObject = mainData.reduce((acc, { phrase, categorynumber, optionnumber }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [categorynumber]: {
    ...(acc[categorynumber] ?? {}),
    [optionnumber]: [...(acc[categorynumber]?.[optionnumber] ?? []), phrase]
  }
}), {});

console.log(jsObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<!--

jsObject = {
  1: {
    1: ["Phrase 1"],
    2: ["Phrase 2"]
  },
  2: {
    1: ["Phrase 3"]
  },
  3: {
    1: ["Phrase 4", "Phrase 5"],
    2: ["Phrase 6"]
  }
}

-->
```

Comment: If you're going to use `reduce` maybe add a link to the MDN documentation because I doubt the OP will understand what it is.

Comment: This code skipped "Phrase 4" completely.

Comment: This solution is incomplete (aside from doing the OP's due diligence for them).

Comment: @ham17 updated, I missed the spreading of the phrase array.

Comment: On a light note, would it be possible to give a step by step guide how this solution works, or at least some resources where this could be understood more elaboratively?